# Express & MongoDB: Duplicate documents created at the timestamp

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, axios

I am using express with MongoDB as a database and while I am sending requests using Axios library to my backend, I have found that two documents were created at the time. I figured that out by checking the `createdAt` field and found the two documents have the exact timestamp. I am creating `createdAt & updatedAt` fields using mongoose-timestamp2

Here is the code responsible for sending the documents which have isSynchronized flag set to false

```js
const syncExams = async (token) => {
  let examSyncError;
  await Exam.find({ isSynchronized: false })
    .cursor()
    .eachAsync(async (exam) => {
      // use try/catch inside the loop
      // so if problem occured in one document, others will be posted normally
      try {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("exam", JSON.stringify(exam));

        Object.keys(exam.images.toJSON()).forEach((key) => {
          formData.append("images", fs.createReadStream(exam.images[key]));
        });

        const res = await axios.post(`${BACKEND_URL}/exams/`, formData, {
          maxContentLength: Infinity,
          maxBodyLength: Infinity,
          headers: {
            ...formData.getHeaders(),
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        });
        console.log(res);

        exam.isSynchronized = true;
        await exam.save();
      } catch (err) {
        examSyncError = err;
      }
    });
  if (examSyncError) {
    throw examSyncError;
  }
};
```

And here is the controller responsible for handling the coming request and creating these documents in the database.

```js
router.post(
  "/exams",
  fileUpload.array("images"),
  trimmer,
  syncControllers.postExam
);
```

```js
const postExam = async (req, res, next) => {
  let createdExam;
  let exam;
  let patient;

  try {
    const reqBody = JSON.parse(req.body.exam);
    reqBody.operator = reqBody.creator;
    delete reqBody._id;
    delete reqBody.creator;

    const { nationalID } = reqBody;

    patient = await Patient.findOne({
      "personalData.nationalID": nationalID,
    }).exec();

    if (!patient) {
      return next(errorEmitter("exams.get-patient.not-found", 404));
    }

    createdExam = new Exam(reqBody);

    // insert the new paths of the images
    Object.keys(reqBody.images).forEach((key, index) => {
      createdExam.images[key.replace("Path", "")].Path = req.files[index].path
        .split(path.sep)
        .slice(-3)
        .join(path.sep);
    });

    createdExam.patient = patient._id;

    const checkDate = new Date(createdExam.examDate);
    checkDate.setMonth(checkDate.getMonth() - 3);

    const nearExam = await Exam.findOne({
      patient: createdExam.patient,
      examDate: { $gte: checkDate, $lt: createdExam.examDate },
      isGradable: true,
    });

    if (nearExam) {
      createdExam.isGradable = false;
    }

    exam = await createdExam.save();
    patient.exams.push(createdExam);
    await patient.save();
  } catch (err) {
    return next(errorEmitter("exams.create.fail", 500));
  }

  return res.status(201).json(exam.toObject({ getters: true }));
};
```

I am using the following package for `createdAt & updatedAt` records created using this plugin.

```js
const timestamps = require("mongoose-timestamp2");
examSchema.plugin(timestamps);
```

This problem occurred in two or three cases only and did not happen again until then and I could not replicate the error. I do not what caused this!

What could cause this problem to occur? Is it possible that Axios sent the same request multiple times and mongoose created two documents at the same exact time, or it could be a bug in `mongoose-timestamp2` plugin?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: which part of that is creating timestamps?

Comment: @Joe
this plugin `examSchema.plugin(timestamps);` creates two records automatically `updatedAt & createdAt` for all the documents created in the database through mongoose. 
This is used in Exam model schema.

Comment: What is the resolution of the timestamp?  Two documents created during the same second is not out of the ordinary.  You are calling save inside an async function called in a loop, so two documents created during the same millisecond is possible.

Comment: @Joe 
Is it ordinary for a timestamp like this `"2021-02-02T20:54:17.330Z"`? I just want to figure out whether the error was caused by mongoose or axios sent two duplicate requests of the same object at the same exact time?